# Getting false-positives in Magento when validating number of items to add to cart

Tags: php, javascript, validation, magento

When a visitor enters a string in the quantity field of the "Add to Cart" input box, Magento doesn't throw an error, but instead accepts the string and interprets it as the quantity "1". How can I change this so that validation recognizes strings as invalid input? There already exists an `onClick` function on the "Add to Cart" button, so I don't think I can attach my own validation code to that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting at a product level which is called "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" that may be set to one.

Comment: thanks man, i will checked it and made it as default to one. its not working